# Using 'C' library with POSIX for windows 8 Apps

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-8

I'm a absolute newbie to windows programming. Im writing some app which will use a 'C' library(will include some POSIX APIs as well). This library will also be written by me.

As far as portability issues, i think i can manage to work this library out for iOS, Android and Linux platforms, but when i want to port it to windows, I'm not sure how it will work. Could somebody explain?

Basically i need a compiler which can compile my library, basically i need GCC for windows(not sure what i can use - MinGW ruled out as they say no support for POSIX). I don't know if it can be done on Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a question that can be answered with a clear "Yes, but..." ;) When you say 'POSIX', which function set are you referring to?

Especially file-related functions are severely reduced in usefulness by the sandbox. E.g. fopen will only work with files inside your app bundle or localStorage.

Others, like strncasecmp can be made to compile on Win8 using a #define because there are other functions with the same signature available (_strnicmp). For even another set of functions (strcpy), Microsoft provides enhanced versions (strcpy_s) which work a bit differently. You can still use the old ones, though, by disabling the secure variants with a #define.

In the end you'll probably need a mixture of #ifdef-encapsulated sections in your library code and maybe some wrapper to wrap synchronous code in a nice asynchronous fashion as is expected in W8 apps.

Comment: Hmm.. got the idea of several #ifdef's but i was looking at the API as such!., in particular semaphores and spinlocks... and which library will i link with? like -lpthread, what is the equivalent of it in windows., and what should be the compiler that i should use?

Comment: For the compiler you're probably stuck with MS Visual Studio. I'd consider using Premake or such for a cross-platform project. If you want to also create a WinRT component, you'll probably need to do extra work. Regarding pthreads and such is what I was referring to in my original post: you'll need to write platform-specific code if you're looking for Win8 compatibility. Here's a list of allowed functions that are compatible to Win8 store apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205762.aspx#threads_and_synchronization